# Getting Error while submitting data on the Profile page - Attached screenshot

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

I am getting the error as mentioned in screenshot below while submitting data for my profile.

[image]

Comment: Getting this error repeatedly, for all options.

Comment: Does it happen if you remove <?

Comment: Do you see anything in your browser's developer tools (Network tab or console especially) ?

Comment: How do I get that page?  A link will help.

Comment: @PedroLobito, I tried what you said, but couldn't remove the <?

Comment: @JonasCz, No errors observed in Developers console.

Comment: @Sid: Check the network tab

Comment: @dan-klasson, no errors in Network tab as well.